# Can't refrence PyQt5 from pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, pyqt5

I am using PyCharm 2020.2 and I can't access PyQt5. From the Python interpreter it is showing PyQt5 ver 5.15.0.  when I run this simple code

```
    import sys
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QWidget()
    window.show() 
    app.exec_()
```

I am getting the following error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

I have no idea where to go next.

Comment: Is "the Python interpreter" the same interpreter that is used in PyCharm?

Comment: Have you installed pyqt5?

Comment: I am not sure how to check the Python interpreter?  Yes, I have installed pyqt5, I just reran  pip3 install pyqt5 and received the Requirement already satisfied message

Comment: @JohnKirkman See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: In pycharm try installing it in the "console" tab at the bottom. Just to confirm you have it installed under the current environment

Comment: Here is a copy of the PyCharm  Python Interpreter; Python 3.8 C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe 
Included in the 13 files are:
PyQt5  5.15.0  5.15.0
PyQt5-sip 12.8.0  12.8.0
PyQt5-stubs 5.14.2.2 5.14.2.2
pyqt5-tools 5.15.0.1.7 5.15.0.1.7
All of my project files are located : C:\Users\john\PycharmProjects\NonProfit
Again, I am very new at this.

Comment: I still can't get PyQt5 to run in PyCharm. I finally searched for "PyQt5" and deleted every file. I then reinstalled PyQt5 via PIP3. Now when I run the program, I don't get can't find module error, i get "not a valid Win32 application"  I really would appreciate any help.